# .NET Remoting replaced by WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, .net-remoting

I heard that .NET Remoting is replaced by WCF. Can someone tell me some details about it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the MSDN White Paper on how to migrate from .NET remoting to WCF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730857%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

WCF is the unified communications stacks that is intended to replace ASMX web services, .NET Remoting, WSE and a few other technologies, too.

Answer (score 3):

.NET remoting is the past, don't use it anymore if possible. WCF supports webservices but binary protocols, too. It's a clean design and a good implementation. It knows everything that remoting and more. There's tons of documentation on the web.